# PHP - get_file_contents not working as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, file-get-contents, array-splice

I'm using a `$file_contents = file_get_contents($file_name)` then using `$file_contents = array_splice($file_contents, 30, 7, 'changedText')` to update something in the file code. However, this keeps resulting in:

```
Warning: array_splice(): The first argument should be an array
```

From what I understand the string returned by file_get_contents() should be able to be acted on like any other array. Any reason I'm having trouble with this? Thank you much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string

So you don't have an array. You have a string.

Comment: file() function reads file into an array of lines. I think question is about accessing string characters via squared brackets, which looks like an array, but in fact it's not - it's just a PHP helpful syntax.

Comment: Yeah - that's why I added answer as well. But you were faster :)

Comment: Ah, then my mistake was thinking a string was an array. For some reason that was my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

String is not an array even when it supports using square brackets:

```
$str[0]
```

Use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) function for behavior you want. It will convert your string into real array, and then you can use it as an argument in `array_splice` function. E.g:

```
echo('<pre>');
var_dump(array_slice(str_split("Stack Overflow"), 6));
echo('</pre>');
die();
```

I think it helps.

Comment: Thanks, my confusion was in assuming a string was a form of array in PHP.

Comment: That's why `str_split` can help you in converting string to an array;)